# setting a default location for files created by ofstream

Tags: c++, macos, codeblocks

i have created a program on code blocks on mac that allows you to read contents from a file as well as write to them. i am able to read the file as well as write into it, but i couldnt seem to find the file itself unless i used spotlight. i thought the files created by ofstream were located in the same directory the project is in by default, but it is not there. what i would like to know is if there is a way to set the default location for files as the same directory for the project itself?

Comment: I don't think so. `ofstream out(const char* location)`

Comment: There is no way to do this in the current C++ standard. Each OS has a different way to get the location of the running executable, and unfortunately, I don't know how to do it in a on a Mac. `_NSGetExecutablePath` looks promising, though.

Answer (score 1):

> i thought the files created by ofstream were located in the same directory the project is in by default

The file will be created at the default directory where your program is started, that's not necessarily the same as the directory of your IDE's project directory.

> i would like to know is if there is a way to set the default location for files as the same directory for the project itself?

Most modern IDE's give you an option to change that from the defaults.